# System modular equation. Question.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$$2x \equiv 4 \mod 8  \iff x \equiv 2 \mod 4 $$
And this is true, but is it a true?:
$$\begin{cases} 2x \equiv 4 \mod 8 \\ x \equiv 2 \mod 6 \end{cases} $$ $$\iff$$ \begin{cases}  x \equiv 2 \mod 4\\ x \equiv 2 \mod 6 \end{cases}  $$
Why? Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following equivalences$$2x\equiv 4 \pmod 8 \iff 8 \mid (2x-4) \iff 4\mid (x-2) \iff x\equiv 2 \pmod 4 $$

Comment: It's true. But is it true when it comes to system equation?

Comment: @user180834  It is true means it should hold in any circumstance, where the same basic axioms hold.  Why do you have a doubt when it comes to systems of modular equations?

Comment: $$\begin{cases} 2x \equiv 4 \mod 8 \\ x \equiv 2 \mod 6 \end{cases} $$ $$\iff$$ \begin{cases}  x \equiv 2 \mod 4\\ x \equiv 2 \mod 6 \end{cases}  $$
So is it true? The both have the same solution?

Comment: Yes. Try solving it.